# how to use html 5 <caption> tag for images rather than tables

Tags: html, tags, caption

I'm redoing the html my team has been working on.. and i was wondering if I can modify html 5 tags.  Specifically I would like to use the  tag for images rather than tables..

in w3schools:

`*Definition and Usage:
The <caption> tag defines a table caption.
The <caption> tag must be inserted immediately after the <table> tag.
You can specify only one caption per table.
Usually the caption will be centered above the table*.`

How can I strip this tag from all these requirements?

Comment: upon further digging.. what i'm asking for is not a good idea.. it's not really good for 'maintainability' of the code.. meaning that if i strip html 5 tags off their meaning.. and create my own.. then i must create a whole html dtd definition.. engineers working on this project after me may get confused about what i'm using <caption> for..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you're after is the [`<figure>` and `<figcaption>`](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_figure_tag.cfm) tags, used to annotate images like you see in textbooks and the like. Caption is specifically for tables.

Comment: Very nice, I wasn't aware of that tag and it's purpose. I still have a lot of learning about HTML5 to do!

Comment: FYI, not everything with a caption warrants a `figure` and `figcaption`. `figure` and `figcaption` shouldn't be used unless their content is essential (not just related) to the content of your text and in most cases is probably referenced from your text. In many cases, an `aside` is probably better. Aside is for loosely related content. [Common `figure` mistakes](http://html5doctor.com/avoiding-common-html5-mistakes/#figure).