# using attribute selectors to style a web page

Tags: css, css-selectors

I found very useful to use css attribute selectors to style a web page, because, for me, it seems to be faster (writing/reading code), than when I used `class=""` or `id=""`.

Is it a good practice, to use attribute selectors to style a web page? and also, Will this work on older browsers?

**HTML :**

```
<div data-header></div>
```

**CSS :**

```
div[data-header] {
  /* style here */
}
```

Comment: This seems to be an opinion poll rather than a real SO question. The small part about support on older browsers can easily be checked from well-known resources like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one problem with using attributes, is that they are invariably tied to a type of html element.. so in the above example, `data-header` can only be applied to divs.. if you want to apply the same style to a `<p>` tag for example.. you will have to write the style again:

```
p[data-header]
```

and since the only advantage that your'e talking about is that it requires less typing.. then that's a trivial advantage (ie we're not talking less processing or rendering time or increased maintainability etc)

I advise you to consider the principles of [Object Oriented CSS](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki) (OOCCSS): where it has this key principle:

*An object should look the same no matter where you put it. So instead of styling a specific h2 with .myObject h2 {...}, create and apply a class that describes the h2 in question, like h2 class="category".*

this makes your css more reusable.. a common problem with poor css management is that you can easily end up with thousands of lines of css.. with much of it redundant.

For a concrete example of how OOCCSS can make css more reusable.. see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15044367/766570)

**important update: what i said above in terms of having a class more reusable than an attribute is not true (see discussion below).. so please ignore it.**

now that being said.. i'd still steer away from using only attributes to style my html.. if for the only reason that you're using a css property for something different than what it was designed for

(in general it's not a good idea to be too clever with your code.. while it may save you time etc.. it can potentially confuse people who will use your code later.. always code with the attitude that other people from all over the world may get their hands on your code.. and so readability trumps less code etc.. esp when there is absolutely no other advantage such as processing time etc).

for example (and I'm saying this without even doing any research.. I'm just relying on my 10+ years exp using css).. if I see this in your code

```
<div data-header>
```

I have no idea if this data-header is a unique selector or can be present else where.. but if I see this:

```
<div class="data-header">
```

then I can immediately conclude (without looking anywhere else in your code) that this is *not* a unique selector.. and that I can very well expect to see other elements in the same page or even other pages that have the same class applied to them..(ie as opposed to using `<div id="data-header">`.. which is then unique)

suppose I'm the javascript/jQuery guy and your'e simply the designer.. that's an unspoken piece of information you gave just by the virtue of you using CSS the way it's designed for.  But then if start becoming all clever and using CSS properties your own way.. then that's recipe for trouble (see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101991/how-to-use-html-5-caption-tag-for-images-rather-than-tables) and the comment I made under it.. It's just a bad idea to get something that means x for everybody and make it mean y just for you).

Comment: "one problem with using attributes, is that they are invariable tied to a type of html element" What does this mean? You can apply any custom data attribute by any name to any type of element, even if you use the same name - there are no restrictions.

Comment: here is an example: if you have class="blue" { color = blue; }, it can be applied the same to a `<p>` or a `<div>`.. but if you have div[blue].. then it only works on divs.. you can't apply it to a `<p>`.. unless if you add another (in this completely redundant) css definition: p[blue].. that's what i meant

Comment: @abbood: You can always use `[data-header]` to style any element with the attribute `data-header`. There is no rule that says attribute selectors must be accompanied by a type selector.

Comment: " even if you use the same name - there are no restrictions".. that's exactly the thing that i want to avoid.. why would I want to use the *same* name twice, for something that will potentially do the same thing..

Comment: Well now I'm confused. Why do you suggest adding the attribute to `p` and using `p[data-header]` then?

Comment: my bad.. forget my last comment.. and you are right.. [data-header] can be applied to *any* element. i will update my answer